# Get JRuby jar path

Tags: java, jar, jruby, filepath

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743854/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-jruby-warbler-jar-file) question, I'd like to know how to get the current jar file's path. But unlike the other question, I want to know the *jar*'s path, not the path of the current file *inside* the jar. For example, say I had a jruby jar at "/Users/MyUser/Jars/foo.jar" and inside was a compiled ruby file at "foo.jar/java/style/class/path.class". How could class.path get the path "/Users/MyUser/Jars/foo.jar"?

I also saw [a way to do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file), but I just don't know how to translate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experimented with this a bit, and any attempt to call the code from JRuby returns the jruby jar itself, which kind of makes sense as the logic is indeed evaluated/executed from that jar.  For instance:

```
require 'java'
puts self.to_java.get_class().protection_domain().code_source().location().path()
```

or

```
require 'java'

class Path
  def get_jar_path
    self.to_java.get_class().protection_domain().code_source().location().path()
  end
end

puts Path.new.get_jar_path
```

both return the path to `jruby-complete.jar`, which can be useful to some extent but apparently not what you’re looking for.

The only way I could get this to work (with `rawr`, but this can be easily adapted if you use `warbler`) is to create a Java class in `src/java/org/rubyforge/rawr`:

```
package org.rubyforge.rawr;

public class Path {
  public String getJarPath() {
    return getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
  }
}
```

Then call this class from the JRuby script:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'org.rubyforge.rawr.Path'

puts Path.new.get_jar_path
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way to do this without _any_ java code?

Comment: I have added my JRuby attempts that may come handy, but couldn’t get them to really return what you’re expecting.

Comment: Alright, this will suffice! Also, the `to_java` is partly what I was looking for; I couldn't find how to call methods defined on Java's Object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out without using java

```
def get_jar_path
    scriptpath = __FILE__[/(.*)\/.+\.jar!/]
    $1[6..-1]
end
```